# Editing the content of a KML using lxml

Tags: python, lxml, kml

I have a simple KML file that I want to modify using etree.XMLParser.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
    <Schema name="test" id="test">
        <SimpleField name="id" type="string"/>
        <SimpleField name="LAT" type="float"/>
        <SimpleField name="LONG" type="float"/>
    </Schema>
    <Folder>
        <name>test</name>
        <Placemark>
            <Style>
                <LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle>
                <PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <ExtendedData>
            <SchemaData schemaUrl="#test">
                <SimpleData name="id">ABC</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="LAT">-35.06111</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="LONG">138.58389</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>138.58389,-35.06111 138.585208,-35.059241 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

First, how can I change the schema id under document and schemaUrl under Placemark from 'test' to say 'test_1'? I tried this, but didn't work:

```
ns = {"kml": "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}
schema_element = placemark.xpath("kml:ExtendedData/kml:SchemaData[@schemaUrl]", namespaces=ns)[0]
schema_element.text = 'test_1'
```

Second, I want to insert a new style for the document. I was thinking to create a string, and a string_element. Insert the string_element under document:

```
style_element = etree.Element(etree.QName(ns.get("kml"), "style"), nsmap=ns)
style_element.text = style_str   

document_element = tree.xpath("//kml:Document", namespaces=ns) 
document_element.insert(1, style_str)
```

This is the final output that I want:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
    <Schema name="test" id="test_1">
        <SimpleField name="id" type="string"/>
        <SimpleField name="LAT" type="float"/>
        <SimpleField name="LONG" type="float"/>
    </Schema>
    <Style id="falseColor">
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
                <tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td>$[test/id]</td></tr>
                <tr><td><b>LAT</b></td><td>$[test/LAT]</td></tr>
                <tr><td><b>LON</b></td><td>$[test/LONG]</td></tr>
                </table>]]> 
            </text>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>test</name>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#falseColor</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#test_1">
                    <SimpleData name="id">ABC</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="LAT">-35.06111</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="LONG">138.58389</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>138.58389,-35.06111 138.585208,-35.059241 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Show the contents of your `ns` variable, as well as how you arrive at the `placemark` variable. (in short: make a [mcve])

Comment: @Tomalak, just added the ns. Not sure if that's ok. I'm very inexperience in both KML and coding, the ns variable is something that I learnt from Googling, and might not be complete. Please let me know if more info / improvement is needed before someone can help with an answer.

Comment: The namespace map is looking good, but it's still not clear from your code what `placemark` contains. Assuming this actually contains the right element, then XPath would be fine, too. However, try setting the `schemaUrl` attribute of the `<kml:SchemaData>` element this selects, instead of attempting to set the `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: `schemaUrl` is an attribute. Locate the element to which the attribute belongs and set a new value:

```
schemadata_element = tree.xpath("//kml:SchemaData", namespaces=ns)[0]
schemadata_element.set("schemaUrl", "#test_1")
```

The `id` attribute on the `Schema` element is updated in the same way.

Part 2: Adding the new style is a little trickier, but not extremely hard. Create the `Style` element as a string, parse it into an `Element` object via `fromstring()` (make sure that the CDATA section is preserved by using the `strip_cdata=False` parser option), and then insert the element at the proper location.

Complete code that does both parts (and removes existing `Style` element):

```
from lxml import etree

ns = {"kml": "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, strip_cdata=False)
tree = etree.parse("your_kml_file.xml", parser)

schema_element = tree.xpath("//kml:Schema", namespaces=ns)[0]
schema_element.set("id", "test_1")

schemadata_element = tree.xpath("//kml:SchemaData", namespaces=ns)[0]
schemadata_element.set("schemaUrl", "#test_1")

# Remove existing "Style" element and add "styleUrl" element 
old_style_element = tree.xpath("//kml:Style", namespaces=ns)[0] 
placemark = old_style_element.getparent()
placemark.remove(old_style_element)

styleurl_element = etree.Element(etree.QName(ns["kml"], "styleUrl"))
styleurl_element.text = "#falseColor"
placemark.insert(0, styleurl_element)

# Add new "Style" element 
style_str = """
<Style id="falseColor" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
            <tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td>$[test/id]</td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>LAT</b></td><td>$[test/LAT]</td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>LON</b></td><td>$[test/LONG]</td></tr>
            </table>]]> 
        </text>
    </BalloonStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
       <colorMode>random</colorMode>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>"""

style_element = etree.fromstring(style_str, parser)

document_element = tree.xpath("//kml:Document", namespaces=ns)[0] 
document_element.insert(1, style_element)
```

Comment: That is a feature added in Python 3.6 called [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). If you need this to work with an earlier version of Python, you can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead.

Comment: thanks @mzjn.. Tried your answer, and it works! There's only 1 very minor thing - the style_str is defined with = f"""  ....... """. It doesn't work for me. If I remove the 'f' it has an error:  **bold** XMLSyntaxError: xmlns: '{ns['kml']}' is not a valid URI, line 2, column 43 **bold**   Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You could simply remove the `f` and the `xmlns="{ns['kml']}` bit. It was perhaps a bit "pedantic" of me, but I added xmlns to ensure that the new `Style` element is bound to the same namespace as the original elements.

Comment: I removed the f-string. It was not the main point of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn. Yes, the style_str is working now. However, I believe we still missed to replace the styleURL under Placemark. How can I remove the existing definition of style and insert a styleURL that refers to the newly created style?

Comment: You did not explicitly mention styleURL in the question. It is just part of the "final output". Easy to overlook. I feel that you are asking about too many things at a time.

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. I'll raise another question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hopefully you don't need to post a new question.

Comment: @mzjn, I have a doubt in KML

Comment: can you please join here,https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214097/kml-creating

Comment: @CodeLღver: if you have a problem, please ask a new question.